# How do I use an object I only know the name of?

Tags: c#, class, variables, object

I'm working on a project at the moment that will make use of a certain kind of object (which we will call "Machine" in this case. This type of object has parameters, methods etc. pp. and I want to use its methods.

In this special case I will have a text field that allows the user to alter a certain property of an object of my own class, lets call it "Name" for simplicity. This property "Name" can be changed by typing a Name into a text field that is available to the user. Validating this text field will call a method from "Machine" for a certain object of that class which can be chosen from a ComboBox somewhere else on that page.
As these objects are created dynamicly, I have no idea how many of these objects there are and how they are called in particular, I only know that they exist.

How would you approach this kind of situation? Is there any way that you can basicly say "treat it as XY and use its methods as if you were sure it was of a certain type"? (Like a cast?)
Or would you solve this problem in other ways?

Comment: are you dealing with an anonymous objects and need to figure out what it is? or do you know what type of object it is?

Comment: @tomsv : I'm sorry, I never used that before, what does it?

Comment: could you provide more information on the type of problem that you want to solve? There may be a different way to do what you are looking for without trying to manipulate objects at run time with reflection.

Comment: This sounds like you could make use of an interface to define the properties & methods that objects of the class are guaranteed to have.

Comment: @user1666620: I want to use a method (for example a simple set) of that object (lets name it "XYZ") that would let me (for example) set the Name-Property of the object XYZ to the value that was given by the user. Basicly a XYZ.setName = "Userinput" but they "XYZ" part is only available as a string that is selected in a ComboBox somewhere.

Comment: @MikeBeeler: Basicly what I wrote to user1666620, I want to use a method of a certain object of a class. I know the name of the object (as a string) and I know that an object with that name exists and that I can access that object and use the method that I want to use here.

Comment: i think you're taking a simple concept (updating the value of a property of an object, which is stored either in memory or in a database) and trying to turn it into something very complex.

Comment: @user1666620: That might be the case. What would be a simple approach to taking the value out of that textfield and update the value of a certain property in my object? Basicly my approach here is: Take the text out of the text field -> Check what name the object which's set-method I want to use has -> use NameOfTheObject.set(TextOutOfTextField)

Answer (score 0):

Use [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx).

```
dynamic d = machine as dynamic;
d.Name = userInput;
```

That said, if you can force these object to implement an interface with the properties you care about your code will be faster and safer.

Answer (score 0):

You can benefit from using dictionary collection :

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Prop1 { get; private set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; private set; }
    public double Prop3 { get; private set; }

    public Dictionary<string, Action<object>> Updater { get; private set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        Updater = new Dictionary<string, Action<object>>()
        {
            {"Prop1", o => Prop1 = o as string},
            {"Prop2", o => Prop2 = (int)o},
            {"Prop3", o => Prop3 = (double)o},
        };

    }
}

class Class27
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string, MyClass> instances = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();
        instances.Add("First", new MyClass());

        instances["First"].Updater["Prop1"]("hello");
        instances["First"].Updater["Prop2"](10);

        Console.WriteLine(instances["First"].Prop1);
        Console.WriteLine(instances["First"].Prop2);
    }
}
```

Output:  hello, 10

Comment: This looks pretty close to what I was thinking about. Would it be possible to use a dictionary like this to use a constructor for that class that I wrote? Basicly, saying I have a dictionary, have a Key on one side and an object of the class on the other and "build" that object using a conventional constructor?